# get YoutubePlayerview seek bar value android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am using YoutubePlayerview in android applicaiton, which is almost working fine,But now my need is get seekbar value of youtubeplayerview, Mean if any user drag seek bar , i want to show that value on textview parallelly , is that any way to achieve it

Comment: Have u Youtube Sample app

Comment: Yes, But i didn`t  found such a thing, even not in document, What i actually want i user drag seekbar then value of seekbar increase of decrease will be shown on textview, during draging

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
youPlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
```